# refresh parameter in testplan

Tags: hp-quality-center

I added a parameter at a business component.
This parameter will not added to the testplan/parameters.

Same if I change a default value. It will not be refreshed, even it's the default value.

I even restarted HP QC.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon similar problem. 
I have tried to do it other way round and it partially helped:

1. Add new parameter in HP QC in Business Component area, Parameters tab.
2. Go to Test Plan -> Test Script tab. In Iterations column click on 1 Iterations link.
3. In right top corner click on button Create Test Parameters and Create. New value will be added in grid below.
4. Go to Parameters tab - now you should be able to use this param.
5. Go to UFT - parameter should be also visible.